# Plotting log normal density in R has wrong height

Tags: r, probability-density, density-plot

I have a log-normal density with a mean of -0.4 and standard deviation of 2.5.

At `x = 0.001` the height is over 5 (I double checked this value with the formula for the log-normal PDF):

```
dlnorm(0.001, -0.4, 2.5)

5.389517
```

When I plot it using the `curve` function over the input range 0-6 it looks like with a height just over 1.5:

```
curve(dlnorm(x, -.4, 2.5), xlim = c(0, 6), ylim = c(0, 6))
```

[image]

When I adjust the input range to 0-1 the height is nearly 4:

```
curve(dlnorm(x, -.4, 2.5), xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 6))
```

[image]

---

Similarly with `ggplot2` (output not shown, but looks like the `curve` plots above):

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0), mapping = aes(x = x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = function(x) dlnorm(x, -0.4, 2.5)) + 
  xlim(0, 6) + 
  ylim(0, 6)

ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0), mapping = aes(x = x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = function(x) dlnorm(x, -0.4, 2.5)) + 
  xlim(0, 1) + 
  ylim(0, 6)
```

Does someone know why the density height is changing when the x-axis scale is adjusted? And why neither attempt above seems to reach the correct height? I tried this with just the normal density and this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curves` generates a set of discrete points in the range you give it. By default it generates `n = 101` points, so there is a *step* problem. If you increase the number of points you will have almost the correct value:

```r
curve(dlnorm(x, -.4, 2.5), xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 6), n = 1000)
```

In the first case you propose `curve` generates 101 points in the interval `x <- c(0,6)`, while in the second case generates 101 points in the interval `x <- c(0,1)`, so the step is more dense

Comment: And this is similar behavior in `ggplot2` then?

Comment: Yes. You can also change `n` to `stat_function` (default value always `n = 101`)